# The information of header and footer section is missing on last few pages of a RDLC report

Tags: visual-studio, rdlc, nav

I am new to the forum. Nice to meet all of you.

I am facing the problem that the header and footer section are missing on last 17 pages of RDLC report. However, the previous 60+ pages of report is worked well.The header and footer section is containing both static and dynamic data.

After I go to find the solution, I found that the operation code of report should be no problem and the only thing that may be problem is the things on layout may cause the error.

I also try to make the report with two export: PDF and EXCEL.I found that only PDF have this problem but EXCEL don't have this kind of problem. However, I cant find the problem to change the layout.

I am using SQL server management studio to manage database, Microsoft Dynamic Nav 2013 to get the data from database ,Visual Studio 2010 to manage layout of report.

Thus, hope you guys could suggest some idea for me as this types of problem don't have any discussion on internet.

Comment: Are you using subreports or is this a single report? Are you trying to display the same header and footer over your entire report? Is there a difference in data desplayed on the first 60 pages and the last 17?

Comment: The report is a single report.
It is a report that show company detail on header but footer is a textbox that show static text.Each pages of the header is different company detail and the body is show the company transactions list.If a page cant show out all the transactions for the company, the next pages will still use the same company detail on header and  continue its transaction detail.

Comment: And both the header and the footer is missing on the last few pages? Even with the footer only containing static text? As a test, you could order your datasource before loading it in the report, making sure different companies are placed on the last 17 pages, see if you still have the same issue.

Comment: Thanks for your helping , I already solved it. :)

Answer (score 0):

After my mind is dropping into hell and try to change setting of the places that may be cause the error in more than 10 hours, I finally found the solution!!!

In my report body content, it has a list1 tablix to contain a rectangle that contains two tables to show the list of transactions.I just change the KeepTogether to "True" in the properties of the two tables, the list1 tablix, and the rectangle.And change the PointBreak to "end" for list1 tablix.

Thus, the report is worked well in PDF export.